# app.config file in the new .csproj format

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

Visual studio have provided a slimmed-down .csproj file format.

I am trying to build a .NET Framework app (version 4.6.1), but use the new hand-editable file.

Similar to the previous behavior, I want the app.config file copied to the output directory, but renamed to `<output_exe>.config` (where `output_exe` is the name of the executable file).

What do we put in the .csproj file for this to happen?

This does not work, because it doesn't rename the file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="App.config">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: You have to make one custom target or call post-build-event to rename the file for you...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just add the `AppConfig` property that msbuild and tooling expects for this feature:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <AppConfig>App.config</AppConfig>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

This enables the `PrepareForBuild` msbuild target to automatically pick up the file and subsequent build steps can also edit this file as the logical file - e.g. the SDK will modify the startup/supportedRuntime section based on the `TargetFramework` that is defined. Adding this as a custom item or build step would loose this ability.

Comment: Adding this property should not be necessary, at least with the latest bits. Simply having an `App.config` file next to your `.csproj` file will result in an corresponding file in the output directory. Note that if you target .NET Core (including .NET 5 and later) the file is named `MyProject.dll.config`. If you target .NET Framework, it'll be `MyProject.exe.config`.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding scripts like below to do that job:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="App.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

and

```
  <Target Name="MyCustomTarget" AfterTargets="build">
    <Move SourceFiles="$(OutputPath)\App.config" DestinationFiles="$(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).config" />
  </Target>
```

The first script can make sure the `App.config` file will be copied to output folder, and second script will rename the file with AssemblyName(name of executable file) after build target.

**More details:** If we need ProjectName.exe.config, then use `$(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).exe.config`. If we need ProjectName.config, then use `$(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).config`. We can customize the format of the renamed file according to what we need.

Comment: I think you have to explicitly state the file extension: ie `$(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).exe.config`

Comment: @AndrewShepherd Yes, assuming we have one Test.exe. if we need Test.config, then use `$(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).config`, if we need Test.exe.config, then use `$(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).exe.config`, we can customize the format to get what we need.